# Deep Linking in React without React-Native or React-Navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, deep-linking

I have a request from a client to implement deep linking in our React application whereby clicking a link will take them directly into the installed app (potentially to a certain point but not sure on that yet).

To my understanding react-native and react-navigation both handle this as part of a feature set within "Linking" that they offer. However it seems excessive to import a framework just for deep linking (perhaps not though).

After googling I can only really find references to deep linking on react-native or react-navigation.

What is my best course of action?

Comment: Is your application a Web Application with React or is it a mobile application on React Native?

Comment: I believe your client app must allow the deep linking for its own app so you only need to implement a web link as long as they provided. If you are only in charge for the web application, there is nothing you can do about if the mobile app itself does not implement the deep linking

Comment: @fxdxpz it's a web application with React

- Yunhai I would assume they have done that

Comment: Then it's just a regular link. You shouldn't need to do anything in your web app. For example, if the native app is configured to handle links from `https://example.com`, then any such link will prompt to open in the app without you doing anything special. You can also have links like `somescheme://some/stuff`in an anchor tag and the app will handle it. So this is more about configuring native app, not your React app.

Comment: @I2obiN you cannot assume that. You have to explicitly tell them the logic behind this feature in a simple level to let them know the actual work is not from your part. Most clients even your managers have no idea about Programming.

Comment: @satya164 to my understanding now this is correct

Comment: @Yunhai heh I just meant as a hypothetical for this question, of course in reality I will be checking with them.. repeatedly :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's get to some basics first, then it will be clear.

In modern SPA's, say with React, it's common for the SPA to handle navigation itself. You need to use browser's history API. It's because your SPA is just a single index.html with bunch of js code, so it sort of virtual, every page is constructed by your app. In order to not reinvent a wheel, its easier to use some library for that, say [react-router-dom](https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start).

But then everything works as expected, and you have deployed your app. When user wants to get some deep page, say, https://my-awesome-app.com/deep/page/1, browser will just send a request to a server, asking: "Please, server, give me a page 1.html, in folder page, in folder deep". But server doesn't have that file, because it has literally one index.html, because its a SPA application. Then we need to tell the server to re-write all deep routes to index html, here is an example for my app hosted on Netlify:

```
[[redirects]]
  from = "/*"
  to = "/index.html"
  status = 200
```

When user will ask for that page, server will 'redirect' that request to the index.html and my react-router-dom will figure out which 'PageComponent' to render based on that path.

So, you can implement routing in your app yourself, probably using browser's History API, but I guess it might be easier to use library. But it's your call.

On the other hand if your app is not an SPA, the story might be different, because say in NextJS routing is implemented in framework itself, and if used deep linking would require different setup depending on how app is deployed.

Comment: Good answer, thanks for the insight especially around the server app on Netlify

Comment: Please is mine :)

Comment: Sure, happy holidays!

Answer (score 1):

Deep-linking is handled largely by Apple and Google server-side

https://www.adjust.com/blog/dive-into-deeplinking/

React-native provides extended functionality for deep-linking within mobile apps but normal web-applications there is no need to implement it there. Use universal links or Google specific links as standard linking within your web app to enable deep linking